# How to add shipped date to admin sales order grid

Tags: admin, sales-order, shipment, admin-panel, grid

I am stuck with adding new column(Shipped date) to sales order admin grid. I copied the file `Grid.php` from `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order` to `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order` and in the `_prepareCollection()` function added the code

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_shipment_grid','sales_flat_shipment_grid.order_id=main_table.entity_id',array('shipped_date' => 'sales_flat_shipment_grid.created_at'));
```

and in `_prepareColumns()` added this

```
$this->addColumn('shipped_date', array(
      'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipped Date'),
      'index'     => 'shipped_date',
      'type'      => 'datetime',
      'filter_index'=>'sales_flat_shipment_grid.created_at',
));
```

My problem is when there are orders with multiple shipments and when I go to the sales order grid  I get the error `There has been an error processing your request` which says there is a duplicate order id.
If there are no multiple shipments for orders, then the sales order grid is fine and shows the shipped date for the corresponding orders.

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

As the order can has multiple shipments, you may use sub-query:

1. in the `_prepareCollection()`

   ```
   $table = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
       ->getTableName('sales_flat_shipment_grid');
   $shipping = "((select max(t.created_at) from `$table` as t where t.order_id=main_table.entity_id))";
   $collection->getSelect()->from('', "$shipping as shipped_date");
   ```
2. in the `_prepareColumns()`:

   `$this->addColumn('shipped_date', array(
       'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipped Date'),
       'index'     => 'shipped_date',
       'type'      => 'datetime',
   ));`

Comment: Your answer seems to be incomplete, as it doesn't show how to filter by the `shipped_date` when 'fromDate' and 'toDate' values are given to column filter.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the renderer instead, and this without joining with the shipment grid.

```
$this->addColumn('shipped_date', array(
      'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipped Date'),
      'index'     => 'entity_id',
      'type'      => 'datetime',
      'renderer'  => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_ShippedDate',
      'filter_condition_callback'
                                       => array($this, '_filterShippedDate'),

));
```

You should create the renderer in your module, and to define your filter function, and you are gonna have the shipped dates, no matter how much shipment you have.

Comment: Thanks Quafae. I am not familiar with creating a renderer. Can you point me towards how to do this?

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/